# Slow loading time in excel from VBA for combo box and command button

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox, commandbutton

I created an excel template so I can type in a name and pull from a dropdown list, then populate the next empty cell in a column with the name at the click of the . It works, but is very slow. I used some tricks I found online to help speed it up, but none made a significant increase in speed. I think I may need to store the list in a memory based array which is only run at the opening of the workbook - I believe scanning the list for relevant choices for the drop down is the slowing the process down, but I am not sure about this or how to do this.

```
Public Sub ListRange_Var()

With Me.ComboBox1

.List = Worksheets("Picklist Options").Range("A3",Worksheets("Picklist Options").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

.ListRows = WorksheetFunction.Min(10, .List)

.Dropdown

.LinkedCell = "FWDCalendar!B2"

IF Len(.Text) Then

For I = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

If InsStr(1, .List(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i

Next

.Dropdown

End IF

End With

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim I as Long

If Not ISArrow Then 

Call ListRange_Var

End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode as MS.Forms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

IsArrow = KeyCode = vbKeyUp) or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)

If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Picklist Options").Range("A3", Worksheets("Picklist Options").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: How many items in the list, and what % are you removing?  It might be better to do the removal in the array before you assign it to the combobox's `List` property

Comment: This works fine for me - no noticeable lag with ~3k entries.  Maybe you can add some detail on what your picklist looks like.

Comment: There are >15k items in the column list - maybe using big O would help speed it up?

Comment: What is "big O" in this context?

Comment: I was told it had something to do with starting at "O" in a search instead of "A" and cancelling out half of the list and making the search logarithmically faster with each additional character

Comment: "Big O" typically means this in programming/algorithms - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation  What you're describing sounds more like binary search, but you're checking for any matching substring (ie. not just "begins with", so I'm not sure that would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which filters the list before assigning it to the combobox.  I see good performance even with 15k items.

This is using a list in ColA and the combobox is on the same worksheet in ColB (positioned on cell selection using the Seelction_change event)

Code is in the worksheet module.  I dod see some "ghosting" of the combo as it moves around, but that's another problem.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim IsArrow As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B"))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Me.ComboBox1
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            
            Debug.Print .LinkedCell
            .Visible = False
            DoEvents
            .Visible = True
            DoEvents
            .LinkedCell = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address(False, False)
            .Top = rng.Top
            .Left = rng.Left
            .Text = ""
            ListRange_Var
            .Activate
         Else
            .Left = 500
            .LinkedCell = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub ListRange_Var()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .List = FilteredList(.Text)
        .ListRows = WorksheetFunction.Min(10, .List)
        .DropDown
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Not IsArrow Then ListRange_Var
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    IsArrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.ComboBox1.List = FilteredList
End Sub

'return an array of items, potentially filtered according to
'  user-entered value in combobox
Function FilteredList(Optional v As String = "")
    Dim arr, arrOut, i  As Long, n As Long
    With Worksheets("Picklist Options")
        arr = .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    If Len(v) = 0 Then
        FilteredList = arr
    Else
        arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
        ReDim arrOut(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
        n = LBound(arr) - 1
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(1, arr(i), v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                arrOut(n) = arr(i)
            End If
        Next i
        If n > LBound(arr) - 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrOut(LBound(arrOut) To n)
            FilteredList = arrOut
        Else
            FilteredList = Array("")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Is it also faster if the list is in the same sheet?

Comment: It should not matter where the list is.